# Python Libraries - Publication Citation Splits

Tags: python, citations, biblatex

I have bunch of citations strings that I want to split them into a single citation. Here is an example I found from OWL citation website. I have combinations of MLA, APA,..etc citation types. Is there a python library or another application that can split these strings into elements in the list. I tried avoiding regex due to citation types variety and I also tried splitting by '/n', however, some of my string doesn't have the '/n' delimiters...so you can see the issue. I am wondering if there is a better way to capture. I am not looking for capturing the name, dates, title...found a library that does that...I just need the strings separated. Any help would be really appreciated!!!! Thanks!!

**Input String - Sample**

```
Dean, Cornelia. "Executive on a Mission: Saving the Planet." The New York Times, 22 May 2007, www.nytimes.com/2007/05/22/science/earth/22ander.html?_r=0. Accessed 12 May 2016.

Ebert, Roger. Review of An Inconvenient Truth, directed by Davis Guggenheim. rogerebert.com, 1 June 2006, www.rogerebert.com/reviews/an-inconvenient-truth-2006. Accessed 15 June 2016.
```

**Output - Sample**

```
['Dean, Cornelia. "Executive on a Mission: Saving the Planet." The New York Times, 22 May 2007, www.nytimes.com/2007/05/22/science/earth/22ander.html?_r=0. Accessed 12 May 2016.',
'Ebert, Roger. Review of An Inconvenient Truth, directed by Davis Guggenheim. rogerebert.com, 1 June 2006, www.rogerebert.com/reviews/an-inconvenient-truth-2006. Accessed 15 June 2016.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `split` and then remove empty elements with `filter`:

```
string = '''Dean, Cornelia. "Executive on a Mission: Saving the Planet." The New York Times, 22 May 2007, www.nytimes.com/2007/05/22/science/earth/22ander.html?_r=0. Accessed 12 May 2016.

Ebert, Roger. Review of An Inconvenient Truth, directed by Davis Guggenheim. rogerebert.com, 1 June 2006, www.rogerebert.com/reviews/an-inconvenient-truth-2006. Accessed 15 June 2016.'''

result = list(filter(None, string.split('\n')))
```

Output:

```
['Dean, Cornelia. "Executive on a Mission: Saving the Planet." The New York Times, 22 May 2007, www.nytimes.com/2007/05/22/science/earth/22ander.html?_r=0. Accessed 12 May 2016.', 'Ebert, Roger. Review of An Inconvenient Truth, directed by Davis Guggenheim. rogerebert.com, 1 June 2006, www.rogerebert.com/reviews/an-inconvenient-truth-2006. Accessed 15 June 2016.']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the string `s` by a newline delimeter `\n` you can use the string method `splitlines()` with a listcomp to filter empty elements:

```
[i for i in s.splitlines() if i]
```